# Automate updates from Azure Function App and App Services to APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Currently I am able to define an API in APIM and import functions from the respective function app as well as app service but what to do if I add a new function in function app or app service and want it to automatically get updated in the defined API in APIM. Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have swagger.json you can automatically import new functions / APIs in your Azure API Management using API Management Suite extension as part of the release process in your Azure DevOps:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stephane-eyskens.apim

Samples / Getting Started:

https://github.com/stephaneey/azure-apim-extension

Comment: Thanks for the response but I do not have swagger in place for my solution. Is there a way where I can use ARM Template and configure it in my azure DevOps release pipeline and get the automation done?

Comment: I don't think so